# How to create json complex object in Angularjs and Spring mvc

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring

I have a form with many input fields to get data from a user. This data is devoted to many objects. I want to create a json object in angularjs with this data and send it back to the server accordingly.

My Java Class corresponds with:

```
public class MyData{
   private List<Data1> listData1;
   private String value;
}
public class Data1{
  private String name;
  private List<Data2> listData2;

 } 
 public class Data2{
   private String address;
 }
```

This corresponds with the following object in AngularJS:

```
 var data= {
    listData1: {
        listData2: {
            address: ""
        },
         name:"",
      },
     value:""
};
```

On the server side, in my controller, I try to retrieve this data like this:

```
 public @ResponseBody List<MyData> save(@RequestBody List<MyData> data){
 }
```

whilst in my angularjs controller I send a post request as follows:

```
 $http.post('/save', angular.toJson(data))
```

but when run it, I get a bad request error. (**400 Bad Request**)

Am I creating the object correctly? Am I transforming it correctly to JSON? Is the communication between the server and client correctly? Which piece of the puzzle is broken or missing?

Comment: have you included any json parser libs in your project like jackson ?

Comment: Indeed, you are probably missing a library that is capable of parsing the incoming JSON into a Java object.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get JSON objects and arrays mixed up.

`Data2` resolves to:

```js
{ address: "" }
```

`Data1` resolves to:

```js
{ name: "", listData2: [ %Data2% ] }
```

`MyData` resolves to:

```js
{ listData1: [ %Data1% ], value: "" }
```

`List<MyData>` resolves to:

```js
[ %MyData% ]
```

An example of expected input:

```js
[
  {
    listData1: [
      {
        name: "",
        listData2: [
          { address: "" },
          { address: "" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "",
        listData2: [
          { address: "" },
          { address: "" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    value: ""
  },
  {
    listData1: [
      {
        name: "",
        listData2: [
          { address: "" },
          { address: "" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "",
        listData2: [
          { address: "" },
          { address: "" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    value: ""
  }
]
```

Comment: in html how set ng-model name? <input ng-model="listData1.name">